# Why won't Python Multiprocessing Workers die?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pypy

I'm using the python multiprocessing functionality to map some function across some elements. Something along the lines of this:

```
def computeStuff(arguments, globalData, concurrent=True):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initWorker, initargs=(globalData,))
    results = pool.map(workerFunction, list(enumerate(arguments)))
    return results

def initWorker(globalData):
    workerFunction.globalData = globalData

def workerFunction((index, argument)):
    ... # computation here
```

Generally I run tests in ipython using both cPython and Pypy. I have noticed that the spawned processes often don't get killed, so they start accumulating, each using a gig of ram. This happens when hitting ctrl-k during a computation, which sends multiprocessing into a big frenzy of confusion. But even when letting computation finish, those processes won't die in Pypy.

According to the documentation, when the pool gets garbage collected, it should call `terminate()` and kill all the processes. What's happening here? Do I have to explicitly call `close()`? If yes, is there some sort of context manager that properly manages closing the resources (i.e. processes)?

This is on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: upvote for a true capitalist title

Comment: Maybe you simply need to add ``try: ... finally: pool.terminate()``?

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear - I'm saying workers stick around even when computation finishes. Although they shouldn't, if I understand the documentation correctly, in any case.

Comment: ...I want to understand more about what's happening. But I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyPy's garbage collection is lazy, so failing to call `close` means the `Pool` is cleaned "sometime", but that might not mean "anytime soon".

Once the `Pool` is properly `close`d, the workers exit when they run out of tasks. An easy way to ensure the `Pool` is closed in pre-3.3 Python is:

```
from contextlib import closing

def computeStuff(arguments, globalData, concurrent=True):
    with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initWorker, initargs=(globalData,))) as pool:
        return pool.map(workerFunction, enumerate(arguments))
```

Note: I also removed the explicit conversion to `list` (pointless, since `map` will iterate the `enumerate` iterator for you), and returned the results directly (no need to assign to a name only to return on the next line).

If you want to ensure immediate termination in the exception case (on pre-3.3 Python), you'd use a try/finally block, or write a simple context manager (which could be reused for other places where you use a `Pool`):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def terminating(obj):
    try:
        yield obj
    finally:
        obj.terminate()

def computeStuff(arguments, globalData, concurrent=True):
    with terminating(multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initWorker, initargs=(globalData,))) as pool:
        return pool.map(workerFunction, enumerate(arguments))
```

The `terminating` approach is superior in that it guarantees the processes exit immediately; in theory, if you're using threads elsewhere in your main program, the `Pool` workers might be forked with non-daemon threads, which would keep the processes alive even when the worker task thread exited; `terminating` hides this by killing the processes forcibly.

If your interpreter is Python 3.3 or higher, the `terminating` approach is built-in to `Pool`, so no special wrapper is needed for the `with` statement, `with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initWorker, initargs=(globalData,)) as pool:` works directly.